# Duplicate code in webpage not sure how to differentiate to click on one particular options list

Tags: selenium

I need to select values ABCD, EFGH and IJKL from a dropdown list.

I tried the code below, but it gets stuck after clicking on the text box where all the options are present in dropdown.

I think this is because in HTML webpage same dialog box is present with same name with different options in drop down list and so it gets stuck and gets confused. Am I right to think this?

HTML code of dropdown:

```
<span class="k-widget" style="width: 200px;" title="" 
    class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header required k-invalid"
    unselectable="on" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" 
    aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" 
    aria-owns="numberTypeDropDown_listbox"
    aria-disabled="false" aria-busy="false">

    <span class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default" unselectable="on" >
        <span class="k-input ng-scope" unselectable="on"></span>
        <span class="k-select" unselectable="on" aria-label="select">
            <span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-60-down"></span>
        </span>
    </span>

    <select id="numberTypeDropDown" class="required k-invalid" 
        name="ProductRelatedNumberType" 
        kendo-drop-down-list="productRelatedNumberTypeDropDown"
        k-data-source="RelatedNumberTypesSource" k-data-value-field="'Value'" 
        k-data-text-field="'Text'" k-auto-bind="false"
        k-value-primitive="true" k-change="RelatedNumberTypeChanged" 
        validationmessage="Related Number Type is required"
        k-ng-model="RelatedNumberType" style="width: 200px; display: none;" 
        required="" data-role="dropdownlist"
        aria-invalid="true">

        <option value="ABCD">ABCD</option>
        <option value="EFGH">EFGH</option>
        <option value="IJKL">IJKL</option>
        <option value="MNOP">MNOP</option>
        <option value="QRST">QRST</option>
    </select>
```

Selenium code I tried:

```
List<WebElement> dropdown=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@id='numberTypeDropDown_listbox']"));
List<WebElement> dropdown3= dropdown.get(0).findElements(By.tagName("li"));
```

Comment: <span class="k-widget" style="width: 200px;" title="" class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header required k-invalid" unselectable="on" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-owns="numberTypeDropDown_listbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-busy="false">
   <span class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default"> unselectable="on" >
        <span class="k-input ng-scope" unselectable="on"></span>
        <span class="k-select" unselectable="on" aria-label="select"><span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-60-down">
        </span>
   </span>
</span>

Comment: <select id="numberTypeDropDown" class="required k-invalid" name="ProductRelatedNumberType" kendo-drop-down-list="productRelatedNumberTypeDropDown" k-data-source="RelatedNumberTypesSource" k-data-value-field="'Value'" k-data-text-field="'Text'" k-auto-bind="false" k-value-primitive="true" k-change="RelatedNumberTypeChanged" validationmessage="Related Number Type is required" k-ng-model="RelatedNumberType" style="width: 200px; display: none;" required="" data-role="dropdownlist" aria-invalid="true">

Comment: <option value="ABCD">ABCD</option><option value="EFGH">EFGH</option><option value="IJKL">IJKL</option><option value="MNOP">MNOP</option><option value="QRST">QRST</option></select>

Comment: The above is whole codein three parts. I have pasted the code in comments too because in body of the question, I guess the whole code is not shown to everybody.

Comment: List<WebElement> dropdown3= dropdown.get(0).findElements(By.tagName("li")); i am not able to fin li tag in any of the html code.

Comment: Seems you were in the right direction but you haven't shown us the html of the `<ul>` and `<li>` tags.

Comment: <ul unselectable="on" class="k-list k-reset" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" id="numberTypeDropDown_listbox" aria-live="off" data-role="staticlist" role="listbox"></ul>

Comment: <li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item ng-scope" aria-selected="false" data-offset-index="0">ABCD</li>

Comment: Above are ul and li tagname. my problem is same code is written for similar element(add related number dialog box) but with changed values in dropdown. I think thats why ABCD values are not getting selected becasue it clashes with another dialog box values 1111, 2222, 3333 etc.